# is this a memory leak for HttpURLConnection class for android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

So I have a code like this, the reason I write it to a class is because sometime HTTP response can delay or contain error. runOnUiThread required activity

```
public class RemoteUtilities
{

    public static RemoteUtilities remoteUtilities = null;
    private       Activity        uiActivity;

    public RemoteUtilities(Activity uiActivity)
    {
        this.uiActivity = uiActivity;
    }

    public static RemoteUtilities getInstance(Activity uiActivity)
    {
        if (remoteUtilities == null)
        {
            remoteUtilities = new RemoteUtilities(uiActivity);
        }
        remoteUtilities.setUiActivity(uiActivity);
        return remoteUtilities;
    }

    public void setUiActivity(Activity uiActivity)
    {
        this.uiActivity = uiActivity;
    }

    public HttpURLConnection openConnection(String urlString)
    {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (conn == null)
        {
            uiActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Toast.makeText(uiActivity, "Check Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public boolean isConnectionOkay(HttpURLConnection conn)
    {
        try
        {
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            uiActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Toast.makeText(uiActivity, "Problem with API Endpoint", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getResponseString(HttpURLConnection conn)
    {
        String data = null;
        try
        {
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            byte[]      byteData    = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            data = new String(byteData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

I will probably use this class for a few times.
As you can see I do this because I need it to run on thread and making a toast.
The IDE warn I have memory leak but I'm not sure about it.
Is this fine? Or is there a more elegant way to write this class?

Comment: "Is this fine?" -- no. Regarding the leak, you are leaking an `Activity` and everything that `Activity` holds onto, such as its tree of `View` objects.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you teach me how to fix this leak? What is the approach that people should practice instead?

Comment: "can you teach me how to fix this leak?" -- I would not use anything resembling it. Beyond the leaks, pretty much everything you are using there has bee replaced by better options in the past 8 years or so. Please make sure that the books or courses that you are using to learn Android app development were created or updated within the past couple of years.

Comment: our professor showed this example so I don't think we have a free will to change to other library. My best bet is trying to fix this resource leak

Comment: A resource leak won't crash your app (usually). If I encountered this code in a legacy project I think I would keep it as is until I could actually rewrite it in a very different way, using about 0% of the code you see :) Rewriting not necessarily to use libraries but coroutines, lifecycle callbacks or other methods that don't require an activity context like that

Answer (score 0):

When the end of stream has been reached, you have to close the InputStream.

```
 finally {
       inputStream?.close()
    }
```

or try-with-resources construct:

```
try(InputStream inputstream = conn.getInputStream()) {}
```

Also you cannot hold activity as parameter. It will save context when activity is destroyed. Remove that part

Comment: try with resource said
`Cannot resolve symbol 'inputStream'`

Comment: >Also you cannot hold activity as parameter. It will save context when activity is destroyed. Remove that part

So is it I should convert Activity from constructor to parameter of openConnection?